# OpenCV crop around Hough Circle point Python

Tags: python, opencv, crop

I am using OpenCV with Python to find a circle in an image. I was able to find the circle using the Hough Circle transform code from the OpenCV tutorial. I would like to crop a rectangle around the center point of a circle. I haven't been able to get the crop function properly and have tried numerous combinations of the cropping and either get an error or the incorrect portion of the image. Can someone clarify how I should input the crop coordinates? This is the error I keep getting:

> error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Thanks!

```
img = cv2.imread('myPicture.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))


for i in circles[0,:]:
    #draw outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    #draw center of circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

    #crop ROI around circle...? 
    crop_cimg = cimg[i[0]:500,i[1]:700] #crop from x, y, w, h 


cv2.imshow('detected circles',crop_cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're in valid bounds of the original image. The following code's untested but you should be able to resolve possible errors.

Also beware of coordinates vs. row/col indexing (these are mutually swapped). For most opencv methods, coordinates are appropriate but cropping is actually a slicing operation on `nuympy` und as such using row/col indexing.

```
img = cv2.imread('myPicture.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

cropSize = (500, 700) # <- added: what size do you want to extract

for i in circles[0,:]:
    #draw outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    #draw center of circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

    #crop ROI around circle...?
    # make sure the bounds won't under-/overflow
    cropCoords = (max(0, i[1]-cropSize[0]//2),min(img.shape[0], i[1]+cropSize[0]//2),
                  max(0, i[0]-cropSize[1]//2),min(img.shape[1], i[0]+cropSize[1]//2)) 
    crop_cimg = cimg[cropCoords[0]:cropCoords[1],
                     cropCoords[2]:cropCoords[3]] 


cv2.imshow('detected circles',crop_cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This doesn't create the crop around the center of the circle, which is what I'm having an issue with.

Comment: You should swap `i[0]` vs `i[1]` since these are image coordinates `(x,y)`. But for cropping you use `row,col` indexing. i'm updateing the answer

Comment: @lo_rabb have you tested swapping `i[0]` vs `i[1]` plus the suggested limitation within `cropCoords`?

Comment: I tried swapping the i[0] and i[1], which did not work. Unless I am misunderstanding what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the error might come from the `crom_cimg` argument, have you checked the following:

- Is the picture large enough so that you reach the (x,y) = (499, 699) pixel?
- `i[0]` should be larger than 0 and smaller than 500
- `i[1]` should be larger than 0 and smaller than 700

Comment: The image size is 1920 x 1080, so those should be within the bounds. I want to crop around the circle, so I want to start from the center points and get a rectangle around it.

Comment: Can you give us the value of `i[0]` and `i[1]` ?

Comment: i[0] = 1094, i[1] = 458

Comment: That's your problem: you cannot crop your picture from pixel 1094 to 500.
In other words, you do `cimg[1094:500,458:700]`

As mentionned by DomTomCat, you need to swap them

Comment: It does not work when you do `crop_cimg = cimg[i[1]:500,i[0]:700]` instead of `crop_cimg = cimg[i[0]:500,i[1]:700]`?

Comment: I had to change the numbers following after i[0] and i[1] so it would be within the boundaries.     crop_cimg = cimg[i[1]:500,i[0]:1500]     but this puts the point in the middle of the circle in the top left corner of the image and I want to crop around it.

Comment: fixed it! using:     crop_cimg = cimg[i[1]-100:525,i[0]-200:1300]

Comment: that's what i meant by swapping the i[1] vs i[0] coordinates for cropping, in my answer :-)